# Class is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, poloniex

I am new to Python and am trying to connect to Poloniex API.

They provide this wrapper which is great.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib

def createTimeStamp(datestr, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(datestr, format))

class poloniex:
    def __init__(self, APIKey, Secret):
        self.APIKey = APIKey
        self.Secret = Secret

    def post_process(self, before):
        after = before

        # Add timestamps if there isnt one but is a datetime
        if('return' in after):
            if(isinstance(after['return'], list)):
                for x in xrange(0, len(after['return'])):
                    if(isinstance(after['return'][x], dict)):
                        if('datetime' in after['return'][x] and 'timestamp' not in after['return'][x]):
                            after['return'][x]['timestamp'] = float(createTimeStamp(after['return'][x]['datetime']))

        return after

    def api_query(self, command, req={}):

        if(command == "returnTicker" or command == "return24Volume"):
            ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=' + command))
            return json.loads(ret.read())
        elif(command == "returnOrderBook"):
            ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=' + command + '&currencyPair=' + str(req['currencyPair'])))
            return json.loads(ret.read())
        elif(command == "returnMarketTradeHistory"):
            ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=' + "returnTradeHistory" + '&currencyPair=' + str(req['currencyPair'])))
            return json.loads(ret.read())
        else:
            req['command'] = command
            req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
            post_data = urllib.urlencode(req)

            sign = hmac.new(self.Secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
            headers = {
                'Sign': sign,
                'Key': self.APIKey
            }

            ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers))
            jsonRet = json.loads(ret.read())
            return self.post_process(jsonRet)


    def returnTicker(self):
        return self.api_query("returnTicker")

    def return24Volume(self):
        return self.api_query("return24Volume")

    def returnOrderBook (self, currencyPair):
        return self.api_query("returnOrderBook", {'currencyPair': currencyPair})

    def returnMarketTradeHistory (self, currencyPair):
        return self.api_query("returnMarketTradeHistory", {'currencyPair': currencyPair})


    # Returns all of your balances.
    # Outputs:
    # {"BTC":"0.59098578","LTC":"3.31117268", ... }
    def returnBalances(self):
        return self.api_query('returnBalances')

    # Returns your open orders for a given market, specified by the "currencyPair" POST parameter, e.g. "BTC_XCP"
    # Inputs:
    # currencyPair  The currency pair e.g. "BTC_XCP"
    # Outputs:
    # orderNumber   The order number
    # type          sell or buy
    # rate          Price the order is selling or buying at
    # Amount        Quantity of order
    # total         Total value of order (price * quantity)
    def returnOpenOrders(self,currencyPair):
        return self.api_query('returnOpenOrders',{"currencyPair":currencyPair})


    # Returns your trade history for a given market, specified by the "currencyPair" POST parameter
    # Inputs:
    # currencyPair  The currency pair e.g. "BTC_XCP"
    # Outputs:
    # date          Date in the form: "2014-02-19 03:44:59"
    # rate          Price the order is selling or buying at
    # amount        Quantity of order
    # total         Total value of order (price * quantity)
    # type          sell or buy
    def returnTradeHistory(self,currencyPair):
        return self.api_query('returnTradeHistory',{"currencyPair":currencyPair})

    # Places a buy order in a given market. Required POST parameters are "currencyPair", "rate", and "amount". If successful, the method will return the order number.
    # Inputs:
    # currencyPair  The curreny pair
    # rate          price the order is buying at
    # amount        Amount of coins to buy
    # Outputs:
    # orderNumber   The order number
    def buy(self,currencyPair,rate,amount):
        return self.api_query('buy',{"currencyPair":currencyPair,"rate":rate,"amount":amount})

    # Places a sell order in a given market. Required POST parameters are "currencyPair", "rate", and "amount". If successful, the method will return the order number.
    # Inputs:
    # currencyPair  The curreny pair
    # rate          price the order is selling at
    # amount        Amount of coins to sell
    # Outputs:
    # orderNumber   The order number
    def sell(self,currencyPair,rate,amount):
        return self.api_query('sell',{"currencyPair":currencyPair,"rate":rate,"amount":amount})

    # Cancels an order you have placed in a given market. Required POST parameters are "currencyPair" and "orderNumber".
    # Inputs:
    # currencyPair  The curreny pair
    # orderNumber   The order number to cancel
    # Outputs:
    # succes        1 or 0
    def cancel(self,currencyPair,orderNumber):
        return self.api_query('cancelOrder',{"currencyPair":currencyPair,"orderNumber":orderNumber})
```

On a separate file I have this:

```
import poloniex

myapi = poloniex("My APIKey is here","My Secret is here")
balance = myapi.returnBalances()
print balance
```

It returns "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" as well as "E1102:poloniex is not callable."

What am I doing wrong? Again I am new to python and coding so I may be doing something stupid :)

Comment: Maybe it needs to be `myapi = poloniex.poloniex(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a sign that `import poloniex` doesn't actually place a class with that name in your current namespace. Consult their documentation for how exactly to `import`, but frequently in this scenario the solution will be something like `from poloniex import poloniex`.

Orthogonally, you can leave the `import` as is, and instead change your code to use `poloniex.poloniex()` instead of `poloniex()`.

In case that's not clear, we are saying "from *filename* import *classname*" as opposed to "import *filename*"; and the error message is basically saying "*filename* is a *filename,* not a *class* name."

A well-defined module has an `__init.py__` which takes care of these things for you.  Sometimes the author wrote documentation but then forgot to actually set these things up in `__init__.py` the way they had planned.  If they only run tests within their source tree, they are not testing this aspect of the functionality.

Comment: Thanks got it working from your first suggestion! First post on stack overflow and its solved in 5 minutes :)